# List available workflows in Symfony

Tags: symfony, workflow

I am using symfony workflow component in a symfony 3 project.
I would like to list all available workflows.

Is there a way to find that list? I was looking in the component code base but didn't find anything I could start working on.

Answer (score 2):

Just make a debug with search term.

```
debug:container --show-private workflow
```

this would be the result:

```
Select one of the following services to display its information:
  [0] console.command.workflow_dump
  [1] workflow.abstract
  [2] workflow.marking_store.multiple_state
  [3] workflow.marking_store.single_state
  [4] workflow.registry
  [5] workflow.security.expression_language
  [6] workflow.blog_publishing
  [7] workflow.blog_publishing.definition
  [8] workflow.twig_extension
  [9] Symfony\Component\Workflow\Registry
```

The above is a simple and a not usable result for your bussiness logic.

If your intention is to do "something" with the output, take a look at the `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerDebugCommand` and try to extend the command and implement your own logic.

If you extend(which I recommend) the Command you will have access to the `getContainerBuilder` function which gets you the builder container and then you can do `$builder->getServiceIds()` and start a string search inside a loop returning all the matched services and that would be your workflow list.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

The workflows property in the registry is private, so you can access it with ReflectionClass.  I use this to get all the workflows for a particular class.

```php
        $reflectionProperty = new \ReflectionProperty(get_class($this->workflowRegistry), 'workflows');
        $workflowBlobs = $reflectionProperty->getValue($this->workflowRegistry);
        $workflowsByCode = [];

        /**
         * @var InstanceOfSupportStrategy $suportStrategy
         * @var StateMachine $stateMachine
         */
        foreach ($workflowBlobs as [$stateMachine, $suportStrategy]) {
            $class = $suportStrategy->getClassName();
            if (empty($workflowsByCode[$class])) {
                $workflowsByCode[$class] = [];
            }
            $name = $stateMachine->getName();
            $workflowsByCode[$class][$name] = $stateMachine;
        }
```